# Sum column in a DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, col

I am trying to add a sum column to a large file that has dates in it. I want to sum every month and add a column to the right of the last column of that month.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame("6Jun06" = c(4, 5, 9),
    "13Jun06" = c(4, 5, 9),
    "20Jun06" = c(4, 5, 9),
    "03Jul16" = c(1, 2, 3),
    "09Jul16" = c(1, 2, 3),
    "01Aug16" = c(1, 2, 5))
```

So in this case I would need to have three columns (after Jun, Jul, and Aug).

```
  X6.Jun.06 X13.Jun.06 X20.Jun.06 Jun.Sum X03.Jul.16 X09.Jul.16 Jul.Sum X01.Aug.16 Aug.Sum
1         4          4          4     Sum          1          1     Sum          1     Sum
2         5          5          5     Sum          2          2     Sum          2     Sum
3         9          9          9     Sum          3          3     Sum          5     Sum
```

I am not sure how to sum every month individually. I know there are build-in sum functions but the functions that I tried do not fit to my problem because they just do a general sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to R, a good start is taking a look at the `dplyr` ecosystem (as well as other packages by Hadley Wickham).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   mutate(id = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
   gather(date, value, -id) %>%
   mutate(Month = month.abb[apply(sapply(month.abb, function(mon) {grepl(mon, .$date)}), 1, which)]) %>%
   group_by(id, Month) %>%
   summarize(sum = sum(value)) %>%
   spread(Month, sum) %>%
   left_join(mutate(df, id = 1:nrow(df)), .) %>%
   select(-id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion regrading the packages. Both your and Sotos' answers worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You're making life slightly hard for yourself using variables names that start with a numeral, as R will insert an X in front of them.  However, here's one way you could get the sums you want.

```
#1. Use the package `reshape2`:

    library(reshape2)
    dfm <- melt(df)

#2.  Get rid of the X in the dates, then convert to a date using the package `lubridate` and extract the month:

    library(lubridate) 
    dfm$Date <- dmy(substring(dfm$variable, 2))
    dfm$Month <- month(dfm$Date)

#3. Then calculate the sum for each month using the `dplyr` package:

    library(dplyr)
    dfm %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(sum(value))
```

Comment: I think you need to recheck your solution against OP's question (and expected output)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way which adds the new columns at the end of the data frame,

```
cbind(df, sapply(unique(gsub('\\d+', '', names(df))), function(i)
                          rowSums(df[grepl(i, sub('\\d+', '', names(df)))])))

#  6Jun06 13Jun06 20Jun06 03Jul16 09Jul16 01Aug16 Jun Jul Aug
#1      4       4       4       1       1       1  12   2   1
#2      5       5       5       2       2       2  15   4   2
#3      9       9       9       3       3       5  27   6   5
```